# How To Add CSS & JavaScript Into Windows Form Application C#.net

Tags: javascript, c#, css

I have download Microsofts's Windows Form Applications Matching Game samples. When i see the "Description Files", It's Contains CSS & JavaScript Files. How to attach that to Windows Forms Application ?

Microsofts's Windows Form Applications Matching Game samples Can Downloaded at :
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/complete-matching-game-4cffddba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Files attached are for the `description.html` web page, and not for the **windows forms application**.

In this sample, all the Styling of the windows forms screen is done either through **designer** or through **c# code**. Nothing related to `CSS` is found.